# How to call all methods of Bootstrap Star Rating

Tags: jquery, rating-system

I am using Bootstrap Star Rating functionality from this [Example.](https://github.com/javiertoledo/bootstrap-rating-input) I am able to initialize input field as given in example but how i can call click event or other events of this.

I am using this code:

```
$('input.my_star_rating').rating
({
   clearable: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this, if you need to perform something with the selected value:

```
    $('input.my_star_rating').on('change', function(){
      alert("Changed: " + $(this).val())
    });
```

Comment: You can set the initial value like this:  <input type="number" name="the_name" class="rating my_star_rating" value="2"/>.